# Super Beginner - Oracle SQL

Tags: oracle

I am beginning to learn about SQL and our professor told us to do 6 tables with their respective indexes and constraints.

The datatype for some of the columns has to be a positive integer greater than 1. How do I specify this? I already created the table but accidentally put

```
CREATE TABLE Loan (
    LoanID number  NOT NULL CHECK (0>=1),
```

and I am scared I messed up the whole thing.

Sorry if the answer is too obvious. I don't know much about sql.

Comment: Don't be scared.  The neat thing about software is we have powers of UNDO and REDO.  There is no penalty for trying something.

Answer (score 1):

example for setting a constraint for a table column as positive integer is

```
CREATE TABLE Loan 
( LoanID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL 
)
```

`UNSIGNED` will make it as no sign so it will accept only positive integers

IF you need to set as accept something greater than a value you can use `CHECK` constraint it will be

```
CREATE TABLE Loan
(
   LoanID int unsigned NOT NULL CHECK (LoanID > 1)
)
```

but as per MYSQL documentation

> The CHECK clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines.

Comment: Perhaps you missed the part "greater than 1"? Sound like a constraint to me

Comment: @ZoffDino u r right it should be > 1 i didn't check that..thanks

Answer (score 0):

You got it mostly right:

```
CREATE TABLE Loan
(
   LoanID int NOT NULL CHECK (LoanID > 1)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

**MySQL / Oracle / MS SQL Server**

Source: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_check.asp

```
CREATE TABLE Loan1 ( LoanID int NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT chk_Loan1 CHECK (LoanID>1) );
CREATE TABLE Loan2 ( LoanID int NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT chk_Loan2 CHECK (LoanID>1) );
...
Select * From Loan1;
Select * From Loan2;
...
```

Also see: [SQL Data Types](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_datatypes_general.asp)